# invalid old size realloc error, stdin read

Tags: c

I am trying to read stdin. After reaching n chars, reallocate memory, although there are 1 major and 1 minor problem. Reallocate error "invalid old size: 0x0000somenumers" occurs after 1 or 2 reallocations and "MISTAKE!!" doesn't print. Minor problem is that it writes number of character after I press enter.

```
int maxchar = 80;
char *buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * maxchar);
int counter = 0;
char *tmp;

while((*(buffer + counter) = getchar()) != EOF){
    counter++;
    if(counter == maxchar - 1){
        tmp = (char *) realloc(buffer, sizeof(char) * (maxchar + maxchar));
        if(tmp == NULL){printf("MISTAKE!!!\n");break;}
        buffer = tmp;
        maxchar += maxchar;
        free(tmp);
        printf("Maxchar is now: %d\n", maxchar);
    }
}

buffer[counter] = '\0';
// some operations

printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Comment: Aside : The `malloc` in the beginning could be simplified to `malloc(maxchar * sizeof *buffer);` This is much cleaner than your error-prone approach.

Comment: `getchar()` returns an `int`. So the value it returns should be stored in an `int`.

Comment: well, how do I print it when I store it in an int then?

Comment: `int c; while((c = getchar()) != EOF) { *(buffer + counter) = c; /* ... */`

Comment: To expand on the comment by @Spikatrix, the [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function returns an `int`. This is actually crucial for the comparison against `EOF`, since the `char` value for `EOF` could be something completely different when [promoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to an `int`.

Comment: @dzuda11 Except when `realloc` fails and return `NULL`. Then you lose the original pointer and will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the assignment

```
buffer = tmp
```

you have two pointer pointing to the very same memory. It could be looked at something like this:

```
   +-----+
   | tmp | --\ 
   +-----+    \     +--------------------------------+
               >--> | memory allocated by realloc... |
+--------+    /     +--------------------------------+
| buffer | --/
+--------+
```

Since you only have a single allocation, the call

```
free(tmp);
```

will free that single allocation. After that call to `free` you have something like

```
   +-----+
   | tmp | --\ 
   +-----+    \     +-----------------------+
               >--> | unallocated memory... |
+--------+    /     +-----------------------+
| buffer | --/
+--------+
```

That means any dereference of `buffer` will be invalid since it *also* points to that unallocated memory. And of course any further call to `realloc` is invalid as well, since there's nothing to reallocate.

The solution is simple: Don't call `free` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to clean up your code a bit, by rearranging statements, removing casts and putting that `free` call in the right place.

Note that `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.

```
int maxchar = 80;
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * maxchar);
int counter = 0;

int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    *(buffer + counter) = c;
    counter++;

    if (counter == maxchar - 1) {
        maxchar += maxchar;
        char *tmp = realloc(buffer, sizeof(char) * maxchar);
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            printf("MISTAKE!!!\n");
            break;
        }
        buffer = tmp;
        printf("Maxchar is now: %d\n", maxchar);
    }
}

buffer[counter] = '\0';
// some operations

printf("%s\n", buffer);

free(buffer);
```

I see what you did wrong, here. You should only free a pointer when you're done with *the memory it's pointing to*, not when you're done with the pointer itself. Only `free` your last copy of the pointer.